# Cannot see proxy object while using Lightning Web Components

Tags: lwc

Please find below.

[image]

Let me know the procedure to show it as the proxy object in consoles

Answer (score 1):

Proxies are easy to tackle,

Just stringify and parse the Object to show it on the console.

Use:
**`console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(proxyobj)));`**

You could simply stringify it as well:

**`console.log(JSON.stringify(proxyobj));`**

But I would recommend to parse as well if the Object is huge.

Comment: why are you parsing twice ?, he can just stringify once andsee it as a string , would you please consider adding that to your answer ?

Comment: Yes, we can do that, but it is a bit ugly and hard to look at if the Object is huge, I'll add that to the answer anyway :)